# A question regarding C++ template

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose the following template definition (the code is meaningless):

```
template<class X, class Y>
bool FooBar(const Y& val) { return sizeof(X) + 4; }
```

I have found that following calling code was legal:

```
float temp = 0.f;
FooBar<int>(temp);
```

As you can see, the second type parameter `Y` can be omitted. A compiler infers the type of `Y` by looking the argument type of `temp`.

What rule or specification of C++ template allows this? I was pretty surprised to see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is template argument deduction; it is the same as if you used `X` as the type of a value parameter of `FooBar` and called it without any template arguments at all.  There is a document with more details at [IBM's compiler site](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/topic/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/template_argument_deduction.htm).

Answer (score 3):

14.7.1 Paragraph 2:

> Unless a function template specialization has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the function template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires a function definition to exist.

As Jeremiah points out, argument deduction is what you're *really* asking about:

14.8.2:

> When a template function specialization is referenced, all of the template arguments must have values. The values can be either explicitly specified or, in some cases, deduced from the use. ...

The process is described in detail there.

Source: ISO/IEC 14882:1998(E)

Comment: This is what happens with the template arguments are known.  Getting the arguments is done by template argument deduction.

Comment: You're right, section 14.8.2 specifically describes the deduction process.

Answer (score 1):

This is called 'implicit template instantiation'. See the standard, section 14.7.1. I would note that this is very commonly used for function templates.

Comment: Instantiation is when the compiler produces a copy of the function body to run, though, not how it gets the template arguments to use for the call.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't necessarily required to specify each type parameter. Essentially, the compiler figures out Y from the type of the parameter passed in, and you specified X in your declaration. Just another difference between Java and C++.